# Why is fminunc in this for loop giving the same result each time?

Tags: for-loop, optimization, runtime, octave, gradient

I am trying to run 'fminunc' multiple times in for loop.

Part of code:

```
P = 0.70 ;
idx = randperm(m);
X_Training = X(idx(1:round(P*m)),:); 
X_Testing = X(idx(round(P*m)+1:end),:);
y_Traning = y(idx(1:round(P*m)),:);
y_Testing = y(idx(round(P*m)+1:end),:);

s             = 100;
border_all    = zeros( 2, s );
lambda        = 1;
accuracy      = 0;
initial_theta = zeros( n + 1, 1 );
options       = optimset( 'GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400 );

for i = 1 : 1 : s
    [theta, J, exit_flag] = fminunc( @(t) costFunctionReg( t, X_Training, y_Traning, lambda ), initial_theta, options );

    for border = 0.01 : 0.01 : 1
        p          = predict( theta, X_Testing, border );
        accuracy_t = mean( double( p == y_Testing ) ) * 100;

        if accuracy_t > accuracy
            accuracy      = accuracy_t;
            border_result = border;
        endif
    endfor

    border_all(1, i) = border_result;
    border_all(2, i) = accuracy;
endfor
```

I use the output values of "theta" later to check different changing variable "i" (for i=1:1:s..).
Every time I run the script "theta" is calculated, but it does not change in other "for loop" iterations. However, it should be a bit different in every iteration.

At the same time, when I rerun the script, I get new values of "theta".  So, it seems that it is calculated from scratch only at the first iteration and not at others.  Perhaps some memory issue.  Have tried 'clear' function, but the result is the same.

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Dear Ula it is not clear what you are asking. Without some demo code that replicates the problem, what you're asking could be any number of things, and the problem may lie in a number of places. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try editing your question to make it more specific and answerable. To answer your general question though, yes, as long as you're calling fminunc with different arguments each time inside the loop, you should expect for the most part the output to be different each time. If it's not, then you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Dear Tasos, there is a relevant part of code below: 
s=100; border_all = zeros (2,s); lambda = 1; accuracy = 0;
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1); options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);
for i=1:1:s [theta, J, exit_flag]= fminunc(@(t)(costFunctionReg(t, X_Training, y_Traning, lambda)), initial_theta, options); for border = 0.01:0.01:1
p = predict(theta, X_Testing, border); accuracy_t = mean(double(p == y_Testing)) * 100; if (accuracy_t > accuracy)  accuracy = accuracy_t; border_result = border; 
endif 
endfor
border_all(1,i)=border_result;
border_all(2,i)=accuracy;
endfor

Comment: I want to launch fminunc 100 of times and check the best border value (from 0.1 to 1) of logistic regression for each iteration. However, theta  and J are the same for all 100 iterations (do not change after 1st iteration).  They have to be different.

Comment: The code in your comment, put it in your question. This will allow people to study it and answer it. However, from a quick look, it doesn't look to me like you change any of the arguments of fminunc during your iteration. So of course it will output the same result each time. There's also some typos (`y_Traning`) but I doubt that's the main problem.

Comment: Done, code in the question. Yes, I do not change any parameters for fminunc. So, the question is how to call fminunc multiple times with the same parameters during one session in a way that it calculates theta and J at each iteration.  For now, fminunc calculates new values of theta and J  only when I launch the script again.

Comment: Just as a syntactical comment, you do not need the extra pair of parentheses for the test-expression when performing an `if` statement, or when defining an anonymous function.

Comment: As for the main question, again, I'm not sure why you expect the function to return different results each time. If you want different results, pass different inputs. Whether that is a different initial_theta, or a different training set, or a different regularizer each time. Otherwise, why would you expect the optimisation function to give you different optima each time you run it on the exact same problem?

Comment: So, if I launch manually (F5 in Octave) the script, I get every time different results (theta and J). I need to do this 100 times. Two options:  1. Run the program with F5 manually 100 times.  2. Somehow do it with code.  My guess is that when I use F5, Octave clears everything and fminunc calculates values from scratch, but if fminunc is called inside for loop it calculates the same values for all iteration (my guess is that it calculates from scratch at first iteration and use those values for all other iteration because of the same inputs).

Comment: Returning to the initial question, is it possible to force fminunc to calculate from scratch at each iteration inside for loop? Basically to get the same effect as that with launching the code with F5.

Comment: It sounds very unlikely that the for loop has anything to do with your problem. It simply sounds like you have side-effects to your workspace somewhere outside this snippet (before or after) that silently alters the inputs to fminunc each time you run it. E.g. is there a call to `rand` anywhere in the code? Have you tried clearing each time you run the script? Or setting a 'seed' for the random generator? In any case, I don't think there's enough information here to diagnose the problem, but, unless I'm missing something obvious, it is unlikely to be in the small snippet of code posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, I do use randperm (added at the top of the code).  That is why when I launch with F5 fminunc generates new values.  I put that part of code inside for loop and fminunc started calculating new values at each iteration, basically, supporting your early point that inputs have to be different for fminunc to get different outcome.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but please know StackOverflow is not a generic debugging service. It's a Q/A site! Debugging step-by-step in the comments, with the question and code changing each time, is of no use to anyone googling similar questions because there is no specific question or an accepted answer as a result. Next time you ask a question, try using a minimal example that demonstrates the error (not copy pasting all the code) that people can help with _specifically_. Not to mention that, typically, the act of trying to prepare a relevant example helps one find the bug themselves. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get it.  It is not about Debugging. There was not any error, which debugging could help to define. Also, in my initial post there was only one line of code.  All the rest was added jut when I was asked for clarification.  Also, do not understand your mentoring tone. Thank you for the assistance, but I am not sure that it is the right approach to provide bunch of out of scope pieces of advise when you are not asked about them.

Comment: I didn't mean for my tone to be offensive. I'm just saying, this is not how SO works. Questions of this kind tend to be closed more quickly than they get answered. It is not about giving unsolicited advice, I'm just letting you know what they right way is to interact with the site. People here expect an [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](mcve) because otherwise questions are vague and add little value to the site. And it is simply true that typically the act of trying to produce one resolves your problem before having to ask. It has happened to me countless times.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment thread to an answer for anyone googling with a similar problem:

> This is because once you enter the for loop, the inputs to `fminunc` never change again, so you are effectively always calling it with the same inputs, and therefore getting the same output out.
>
> Move the randomized initializations at the top part of your code snippet *inside* the for loop, and you will get different outputs each time, as you intend.